# cvCaptureFromAVI/File not working after reinstalling visual-studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

All the above mentioned functions are returning null when I debug the programs. 
The file paths are correct. 
This happened after I reinstalled VS2010.

I used this code to check ...

```
int main() {
CvCapture *capture;
//capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("Cricketc1.avi"); //does not work
capture = cvCaptureFromFile("drawingroom.flv"); //does not work
//capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); //works
IplImage *image = NULL;
cvNamedWindow("video", 0);
    //while (1)
while (cvQueryFrame(capture)) {
    image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (image)
        cvShowImage("video", image);
    cvWaitKey(40);
}
return 0;
}
```

The window "video" closes as soon as the control enters the while loop ...

Even `cvLoadImage()` is not working.

How should I correct it ??

Comment: cvCaptureFromCAM() has started to work. But the other two are giving the same problem ....

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that path is correct? Try to use absolute path like `D:\\something.avi`.

Comment: Which version of opencv you are using?use CMAKE to build the .sln file and build the libs n dlls using VS2010

Comment: I was using OpenCV 2.3 earlier .... and everything was working fine .... !!!! after I reinstalled I reopened the projects and this error is coming up... So, everything is same like before but those functions are not working.

Comment: @cyriel I am absolutely sure about the path. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was using OpenCV 2.3 earlier but after this problem I installed OpenCV 2.4 and am using it now.
It is working fine now without any unprecedented errors ...

Thanks all!